# C# Display Prev and Next Date at DateTimePicker using Button

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I was trying to display the previous and next date at DateTimePicker while clicking the next button or previous button.

I found a code on the internet but it doesn't work for me. Here is the code:

```
void next()
{
    DateTime next = DateTime.Parse(dt_date.Text);
    dt_date.Text = next.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();
}

void prev()
{
    DateTime prev = DateTime.Parse(dt_date.Text);
    dt_date.Text = prev.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
}

private void btn_prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    prev();
}

private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    next();
}
```

Hopefully, someone could help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `Value` property.

```
void next()
{
    dt_date.Value = dt_date.Value.AddDays(1);
}

void prev()
{
    dt_date.Value = dt_date.Value.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Edit:

I just tried your code and it works fine. You need to add more details.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I just updated my code to value property as yours and now it works. Thank you very much.. I just wondering why the first code is not working.. it seems like others can use the code and it's working fine..

Comment: Are you using a custom display format on the DatetimePicker? That could cause `DateTime.Parse(dt_date.Text);` to fail. Wrap your code in a `try/catch` to see if that is the case.